# Push rejected, failed to compile Python app - Python version error

Tags: python, heroku

I have used Heroku with PHP in the past but this is the first time I am using Heroku with Python and Flask. For start, I want to create a simple "Hello World" app and then upload a more complex program I have built. Therefore the project's folder contains the following:

- One "Hello World" Python script (called `Main.py`):

  ```
  from flask import Flask, render_template

  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route("/")
  def index():
      return render_template("index.html", message="Hello World")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run(debug=True)
  ```
- A `templates` file with a `index.html` file (see above) inside it
- One `runtime.txt` file:

  ```
  python-3.6.5
  ```
- One `requirements.txt` file:

  ```
  Flask==1.0.1
  ```

(The project is originally located at `/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Project_HelloWorld`.)

However, when I enter `git push heroku master` at the terminal then I am getting the following error:

```
Counting objects: 85, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (82/82), done.
Writing objects: 100% (85/85), 5.01 MiB | 3.13 MiB/s, done.
Total 85 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5 (you are using {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200
remote: {\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
remote: {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red43\green47\blue49;\red237\green237\blue244;}
remote: {\*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c21961\c24314\c25098;\cssrgb\c94510\c94510\c96471;}
remote: \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
remote: \deftab720
remote: \pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0
remote: 
remote: \f0\fs26 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
remote: python-3.6.5}, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.5).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200
remote: {\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
remote: {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red43\green47\blue49;\red237\green237\blue244;}
remote: {\*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c21961\c24314\c25098;\cssrgb\c94510\c94510\c96471;}
remote: \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
remote: \deftab720
remote: \pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0
remote: 
remote: \f0\fs26 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
remote: python-3.6.5}
remote:  !     Requested runtime ({\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200
remote: {\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
remote: {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red43\green47\blue49;\red237\green237\blue244;}
remote: {\*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c21961\c24314\c25098;\cssrgb\c94510\c94510\c96471;}
remote: \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
remote: \deftab720
remote: \pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0
remote: 
remote: \f0\fs26 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
remote: python-3.6.5}) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to evening-sierra-26101.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/evening-sierra-26101.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/evening-sierra-26101.git'
```

**How can I fix this error and properly run my app on Heroku?**

Also when I am entering `cat runtime.txt` at the terminal for the `runtime.txt` above then I am getting the following (quite unexpected?) output:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200
{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red43\green47\blue49;\red237\green237\blue244;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c21961\c24314\c25098;\cssrgb\c94510\c94510\c96471;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs26 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
python-3.6.5}%
```

I have firstly tried it with `python-3.6.4` (instead of python-3.6.5) in the `runtime.txt` but I was getting the same error.

Comment: delete `runtime.txt` and recreate it with `python-3.6.4`. Nothing should magically edit the content of that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what it was going wrong and now my "Hello World" can run properly on Heroku.

The problem was the that even though I created anew the `runtime.txt` file and the `requirements.txt` for some reason the following "text" was inserted in them before the proper text:

```
\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200
remote: {\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
remote: {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red43\green47\blue49;\red237\green237\blue244;}
remote: {\*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c21961\c24314\c25098;\cssrgb\c94510\c94510\c96471;}
remote: \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
remote: \deftab720
remote: \pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0
remote: 
remote: \f0\fs26 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
```

This was displayed at the error that I posted above when I was trying to do `git push heroku master` at my app and when I was entering `cat runtime.txt`. I finally spotted this by using a Hex editor. Therefore, Heroku was not only reading `python-3.6.4` in my `runtime.txt` but also all this thing that I posted above before actually reading `python-3.6.4.` and this is the reason why I was getting an error.

As @Chris notes below at the comments, this unnecessary "text' was added (for some reason) because my `.txt` files were firstly saved (for some reason) as `.txt.rtf` and then I manually changed the extension to `.txt` without having in mind that something more was saved in them even thought I changed the extension. I deleted all this unnecessary "text" with my Hex editor and now everything is working fine.

Comment: It looks like your files got saved as [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (see the example in the [code syntax section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Code_syntax)). How did you create those files? Are you on Windows?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Chris. I am using Mac. You are right, my `.txt` files were firstly saved for some reason as `.txt.rtf` and then I manually changed the extension to `.txt` without having in mind that something more was saved in them even thought I changed the extension.

Answer (score 3):

First I'd figure out how to run your app with gunicorn, as that's the most common deployment server for Flask apps. To run your app with gunicorn, you should be able to `pip install gunicorn`, then run from the root of your project: `gunicorn my_file_name:app`, where my_file_name == the name of the file that contains your Flask code above. E.g. if your Flask code is in a file named app.py, you'd run `gunicorn app:app`.

Once you can run the app with gunicorn, create a Procfile that specifies you want Heroku to run the server with gunicorn. Here's the contents of `Procfile`, which should be in the root of your project files (the same directory with `requirements.txt`):

`web: gunicorn app:app`

Then I'd update `requirements.txt`. Do a `pip freeze | grep gunicorn` to get your gunicorn version then add it to the `requirements.txt` file:

```
Flask==1.0.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
```

Finally, to resolve the immediate cause of your error above, I'd set `runtime.txt` to:

`python-3.6.4`

Then `git push heroku master` *should* be able to get you going...

If all else fails, [here's a simple repository](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/44783327ed102fa33bac597a16d5ad10) that has a barebones Flask app with Heroku deployment instructions in the README. It's deployed here: https://myapp-name-1.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer(upvote)! For start, after installing gunicorn at the project interpreter at Pycharm, when I am entering `gunicorn Main:app` (`Main.py` is my python script) at the terminal in the root folder of the project i am getting `zsh: command not found: gunicorn`. (Secondly, when I am entering `git push heroku master` after having done all the other things that you have said then I am getting the same final error regarding the version of Python etc.) Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Poete_Maudit, first. Eyyyyyyy, hello there fellow `zsh` user. Going back to the matter at hand, how did you install `gunicorn`? Have you tried using `virtualenv`? `virtualenv` lets you create a virtual environment where you can install Python packages safely, without the danger of "poisoning" your system.

Comment: The gunicorn issue suggests something's screwy with your Python setup. I'd use Sean's advice or install Anaconda and use a conda environment (they're a little more flexible as with a conda environment you can specify the Python version you want to use in an environment). Can you cat `runtime.txt` and paste the output? Also if you could pastebin or similar the full heroku stacktrace after another git push that would be helpful!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SeanFrancisN.Ballais. I am using PyCharm so I simply go to PyCharm Community Edition->Preferences->Project Interpreter and I simply add the package after finding it. This is how I did for all packages/libraries like Flask, PyMySQL etc

Comment: (@duhaime) Yes, I have already written at the end of my post above what is the output  when entering `cat runtime.txt`. It looks pretty similar to what is included in the error displayed when I try to `git push heroku master` my app on Heroku.

Comment: @Poete_Maudit It's possible the Python to which PyCharm is installing your dependencies is not the Python that you're running to evoke those dependencies. Could you try from a terminal `python -m pip install gunicorn`? This should ensure the Python used to install the dependencies is the same as the version to which you submit code to be interpreted. I'd highly suggest trying out a virtual environment though--they can save lots of headaches. -- Can you please delete runtime.txt and save only `python-3.6.4` to that file then re-push? Make sure nothing else changes the content in `runtime.txt`!

Comment: I entered `python3 -m pip install gunicorn` at the terminal and the output is `Requirement already satisfied: gunicorn in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages`. Also, I did that with `python-3.6.4` but when I am entering ` cat runtime.txt` I am getting the same output with before but simply with `python-3.6.4` than with `python-3.6.5`.

Comment: However, for some reason `gunicorn` is underlined with a red line at my  `requirements.txt` (and at my `Procfile`) while the other requirements are not.

Comment: @Poete_Maudit I made a simple Heroku / Flask sample here. Can you git clone the repo to your Desktop then follow the directions in `README.txt` to try and stand up your app?  To clone `git clone https://gist.github.com/duhaime/44783327ed102fa33bac597a16d5ad10`

Comment: @Poete_Maudit, try typing `which python3` in the Terminal and please give us the output along with the screenshot of the Project Interpreter window in PyCharm.

Comment: @duhaime One question: ```runtime.txt``` you mean ```requirements.txt``` or is that a separate file?

Comment: @Hidot that's a separate file. `requirements.txt` specifies the versions of Python modules used in your project. `runtime.txt` specifies the version of Python used in your project!